# Is it possible to inject provider into the service in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm implementing a custom interceptor for http queries. It requires access to the default headers defined in $httpProvider.

Is it possible to inject $httpProvider (not an instance of $http because this leads to a circular refernce) as a dependency into interceptor factory?

Comment: Are you trying to call another service into interceptor?

Answer (score 9):

No you cannot.

Providers are objects which return you the functions for factories / services / whatsoever and are running **before** your factory is created.

In fact it is going like that:

1. create app
2. attach / define your services
3. configuration step (where you can inject constants and providers)
4. running step (where you can inject everything else) and finally your instances are created and you have your factory instance which cannot change the configuration because it is already done and `$http` is already created and is immutable.

In short: you can inject the providers only in your bootstrap `.config()` blocks before all instances are generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject `$injector` instead:

```js
.factory("MyInterceptor", ["$injector",
function($injector) {

  return {

    response /* or any other */: function(response) {

      var $http = $injector.get("$http");
      // here, you have access to $http.defaults.headers,
      // see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers

      return response;
    }

  };

}])
```

Then, in some `.config()` block:

```js
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyInterceptor');
```

Comment: I don't need an instance of $http. It resolves all registred interceptors including my own interceptor on creation. Thus will get circular reference. To avoid this I'm trying to inject $httpProvider which will not resolve dependencies on interceptors.

Comment: @PavelPykhtin You won't get a circular reference, see my edit (my first answer wasn't very detailed `:)`).

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Yes, this should work. Thx!